# Avoiding JavaScript to use python on HTML with RaspberryPI (WebIO Pi Server)

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi, raspberry-pi3

I am running a personal website and learning basic HTML. I am quite familiar with Python, can connect to database, read of values from sensors and much more, Thus I would like to stick with a language that I know enough. My question is how to tackle the HTML part. Let's say I want to print a value from my database (MySQL) directly on to the webpage. In my case it would be the value of temperature in my room. I know the right way would be to go with JavaScript and connect to the database and link it in the HTML index file, but its really not my area of expertise and to learn a whole new language. What I could do is write a python script to read the MySQL data off, and store it in a variable or even a text file.

What would be the best way to approach such an issue? Can we run or trigger python scripts in HTML? How would we be passing the values between the python program and the HTML?

For the server I'm running WebIOPi, and for the database I'm running MySQL. I can already connect and write to it and also read it back with the python script. Only if I can pass these values to my webpage would really be awesome!

I did manage to find CGI (Common Gateway Interface) for such purpose but couldn't really figure out how to utilize it or how it would allow me to pass variables between the python and HTML.

Any short example or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's time to learn a web framework !

I would recommand Flask, and [this awewome tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).

Install it with :

```
$ pip install Flask
```

Here's a very short example.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>'
```

Run it with :

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello.py
$ flask run
```

If you're on Windows, use `set` instead of `export`.

If ths `flask` command does want to work, try

```
$ python -m flask run
```

instead.